# Processing ACTION_EDIT result

Tags: android, text-editor

I am opening text file for edit by means of:

```
startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent.ACTION_EDIT, SOME_CODE);
```

The question is how I need to know whether file was edited by user or not. Should I use File.lastModified() or you can advice to me some more elegant solutions?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

When your activity sends it's result it can send a bundle, containing an indication of whether the file was modified or not.

In the called activity:

```
Intent ret = new Intent();
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putBoolean("Edited", iEditedTheFile);
ret.putExtras(b);
this.setResult(RESULT_OK, ret);

this.finish();
```

And then in the activity that wants to check:

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (requestCode == EDIT_ADD && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
     Bundle b = data.getExtras();
     Boolean itWasEdited = b.getBoolean("Edited");
      ... do stuff ...
   }
 }
```

Comment: By means of Intent.ACTION_EDIT I am starting default text editor, so obviously I cant get any custom bundles from, doesn't it?